# Unable to merge android manifests

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest, ads, appodeal

I have a problem with ads for unity 
I try to install appodeal ads and when i compile on apk i receive this error :

```html
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Stef/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "F:\Unity full\Unity 5.6\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:7] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-clearcut-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-location-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:71, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:2] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
]
stdout[
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:24, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:23, F:\.PAYED UNITY ASSET - NEVER DELETE\cow vs zombie\Zombies vs Cow\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

How I can fix it ? 
This game is not for cardbord or daydream

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "Minimum API Level" to 14 in Android Player Settings:

[image: Android Player settings]